# Is my electric stove receptacle wired correctly?

Tags: electrical

When I test the four prong electric stove outlet by touching one of the prongs and the ground, one prong reads 120V and the other 220V.

Is this normal or is it wired wrong?

Comment: Please describe a bit clearer what prongs you are testing and what the reading are. Also, why are you testing this? Is it not working properly?

Comment: I hope you are not testing this by simply touching the prongs with your fingers. This could be deadly. Instead you should be carefully probing with the test leads of a suitable meter.

Comment: @MichaelKaras - If his fingers can read voltage then I think he is advanced enough to touch it.

Comment: When you test the "other" one are you still testing it to ground or another hot prong; are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

On a NEMA 14 that is correctly wired:

H1-H2 should be 240VAC

H1-N, H2-N, H1-G, H2-G should *all* be 120VAC

N-G should be close to zero, but not exactly zero.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is normal. There are two hots at 120v.  Hot to hot gives you 240v but hot to neutral or ground gives you 120v.